# RxJava Conditional Zip

Tags: rx-java

I'm looking to join two observables that both retrieve a list of users.
The lists both have incomplete information about the same users. i.e.

```
Observable1
  -Object1 { $userid, username, user_email }
Observable2
  -Object1 { $userid, user_location }
```

Seems like the zip operator is what I need but that joins them by first come first served instead of $userid.

Is there something like a conditional zip?

Comment: you probably have to sort them first

Comment: if both of your sets have the same cardinality and one-to-one mapping between each other, then pre-sorting by $userid before zip will help. However if there is no one-to-one mapping, you can load a smaller set into a HashMap with userid as a key, and use that map while observing the larger one.

Comment: I can make them have the same cardinality, but I didn't think to simply load the smaller set into a hashmap like you suggested. I ended up using that method.